# SQL Server Select data from table without knowing column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is sample data table.

[image]

I want to select values in any rows or any column (equals) = 200  with column names.But **we don't know column names**.

Comment: You mean you want to use SELECT * FROM YourTable?

Comment: No only select any column contain 200 with column names in all rows

Comment: So you don't know `Column1`-`Column5`? Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339785/search-query-on-multiple-columns-of-a-table/23341104#23341104 this may be not the complete answer you are looking for, but you can modify the query not to take column name as a parameter.

Comment: No I don't know column names,but that column data contain 200,then we will print that result with column names.

Comment: Yes I don't want to hardcode column names,because i want to re use the code for different size of with of data columns in another table.

Comment: @TimSchmelter because I have several data tables,So I don't want to hardcode the column names or some time that column count may be vary.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the table name it's possible to interrogate the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, with SQLServer 2005 or better, or `sysobjects` and `syscolumns` with SQLServer 2000 to retrieve the table columns, after that you can create a fully referenced query for your needs

Comment: This answer is probably incomplete, but I'm not downvoting it.  The data type is probably relevent.  Excluding primary and foreign keys may also be relevent.

Answer (score 1):

I think the below T-SQL will get you what you want. It was written against AdventureWorks2012LT. In the future, you can get more specific help by including the SQL create statements with your question (so the responder doesn't have to recreate the tables)
(BTW, My example is looking for any field that contains the letter 'S')

```
DECLARE @column_name nvarchar(200);
DECLARE @statement nvarchar(max);

DECLARE @results TABLE(
id int,
colname nvarchar(200),
value nvarchar(max)
)

DECLARE col_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME AS col
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C WHERE C.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Address'

OPEN col_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor INTO @column_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
PRINT @column_name
SELECT @statement = N'SELECT AddressID, ''' + @column_name + ''' AS ColName, ' + @column_name + ' AS value FROM SalesLT.[Address] WHERE ' + @column_name + ' LIKE ''%S%''';

INSERT INTO @results
EXEC(@statement);

FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor INTO @column_name
END

CLOSE col_cursor
DEALLOCATE col_cursor

SELECT * FROM @results
```